# How to load a specific layout of an activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on an augment reality android app. I developed the app in unity using vuforia and then imported it in android studio as i wanted to design it in android studio. The activity name in generated project structure is `UnityPlayerActivity` which has no layout in the project. The activity is passed to `UnityPlayer`class and the layout is generated. This is some code of my `UnityPlayerActivity` activity.

```
protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

// Setup activity layout
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); // <--- This makes xperia play happy

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
    setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
}
```

as it uses that layout how can i design that activity by referencing it.

[image: Sample screenshot of that app]

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I want to customize the layout but don't know how to target the `UnityPlayerActivity` activity to generate its layout!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this by referencing the object(Java does not support call by reference).

You need to define a new function in UnityPlayer class that generates a layout and returns the LayoutParams object.

Then use the Layout inflator. Something like this:

```
LayoutParams mParams=mUnityPlayer.layoutGenerator() //some function to generate LayoutParams
LayoutInflator.getLayoutInflator().inflate(LayoutParams);
```

Comment: In place of setContentView

Comment: `UnityPlayer.class` class is compressed in `unity-classes`Jar file and cannot be edited (as it is already compiled) or replaced. Then what should i do?

Comment: In that case, you could try extending the class, and then overriding the existing methods.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found an easy solution to my problem. I displayed the unity scenes in a subview using a framelayout and now i can customize the UI easily. Check [here](http://www.41post.com/5292/programming/unity-and-android-create-an-unity-app-with-a-custom-layout) and [here](https://github.com/TTimo/unity-android-example) to see more information.